# ContainerView should optionally decide whether to load a tableViewController or a normal ViewController

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, container-view, multiple-views

I am making an app using iOS 6 and storyboard and am stuck at the following point: I am loading a view which has a container view inside it. This view gets loaded(along with the container view) when a row of table view is selected. Now, I want the container view to decide depending on which row was selected it should load either a UITableViewController or a UIViewController or someOtherCustomViewController. Like say when row 0 is selected the container view should display a table View and when row 1 is selected say it should display a tab bar controller and so on. Since container view allows only one segue to be associated with it, this is proving to be a trouble.

## NOTE:

The original view which contains the container view cannot be deleted as container view occupies only a part of space in the whole view.

Comment: you should really read documentation before asking questions...

Comment: I am new to iOS app development, so can you direct me in the right direction? Which part are you talking about?